# Update access table with values from another table using VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have two tables, table 1 and table 2, in a database.
I am trying to update table 1 using VBA code based on data in table 2.

Example:

Table 1

```
PartNo  Price  Description
--------------------------
A      100    
B      200      Bad
C      300
```

Table 2

```
PartNo  Price  Description
--------------------------
A        700
B        200      Good
D        900      Used
```

After the update, table1 should be updated with those prices or descriptions that have changed where table1 PartNo = table 2 PartNo , and add any new items that were present in table 2.

Table 1

```
PartNo  Price  Description
--------------------------
A      700
B      200      Good
C      300
D      900      Used
```

I can't seem to get it quite right, appreciate the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with two statements, an update and an insert like this:

Update:

```
UPDATE Table1 
INNER JOIN table2 
 ON(table1.partNo = table2.PartNo)
SET table1.price = table2.price,
    table1.description = table2.description
```

And then an insert:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (PartNo,Price,Description)
SELECT PartNo,Price,Description FROM table2 t
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM table1 s
                 WHERE t.PartNo = s.PartNo)
```

Comment: Please include field list in `INSERT` statement - you may run into serious problems, if table structures won't exactly match.

Comment: I think we here should give most generic and trouble-free answers. Maybe OP just simplified his tables? Maybe OP will modify one table structure later? It is just common sense to always specify field lists in such statements :) I have seen numerous problems here on stackoverflow, caused by omitting filed list in `insert` stement.

Comment: @Arvo Ok, I can accept your comment when teaching begginers :) edited.