# Import Excel spreadsheet to Access then populate an Access Table

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I hope you can help me!

I am trying to fill/populate an Access table from an imported table from an excel spreadsheet.

So basically I want to import from the excel spreadsheet into the Access table then I want to fill/populate my main Access table from the imported table.

I need the code also to check if:

- the column name matches then the editing or adding a new record can be done
- check if the value of every field matches between the records in the main table and where the imported data are. if not then update the field. if yes then proceed to the next record.
- the record is not available in the main table then add a new record/row to the last row/record
- it also needs to consider that I have an ID as the primary key

So the step how to import the spreadsheet itnto Access I got already done, but I need the step with adding/editing the records in the main table in access from another table with the steps I've mentioned.

If somebody can help me with that I would really appreciate it and would help me a lot!!!
Thank you!

My code sofar:

to browes where the excel file is:

```
Private Sub BtnBrowse_Click()
    Dim diag As Office.FileDialog
    Dim item As Variant
    
    Set diag = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    diag.AllowMultiSelect = False
    diag.Title = "please select the rawdata Excel spreadsheet"
    diag.Filters.Clear
    diag.Filters.Add "Excel Spreadsheets", "*.xls, *.xlsx"
    
    If diag.Show Then
        For Each item In diag.SelectedItems
            Me.txtfileName = item
        Next
    End If
    
End Sub
```

code to import the Excel file:

```
Public Sub ImportExcelSpreadsheet(filename As String, tableName As String)
On Error GoTo badformat
    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, tableName, filename, True
    Exit Sub
badformat:
    MsgBox "The file you tried to import was not an Excel spreadsheet. Please try again!"
End Sub
```

to initiate the import:

```
Private Sub importExcl_Click()
    Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
    
    If Nz(Me.txtfileName, "") = "" Then
        MsgBox "please select a file!"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    If fso.FileExists(Nz(Me.txtfileName, "")) Then
        Module1.ImportExcelSpreadsheet Me.txtfileName, "importedData"
    Else
        MsgBox "file not found. Please check your file path"
    End If
End Sub
```

The name of the table where the imported data is "importedData"
The name of my main table i "Projects"

Comment: the code so far?

Comment: @Ferdinando thank you for the fast reply. I've added the code to my question

Comment: These two topics have helped me:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6199417/upserting-in-ms-access
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35864736/update-access-table-with-values-from-another-table-using-vba

and then  running the sql query code by using 
`DoCmd.RunSQL`